# How to transform for normal distribution with Python/Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, regression

I am looking for a convenient way to test for normal distribution using Pandas.

Stata has a useful [helper function](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/rladder.pdf) ladder/gladder that calculates or plots several transformations.

I know that R has a similar functionality included with the 'HH' package.

I was wondering if there is a way to achieve a similar functionality with Pandas/Python?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Setup**

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 1.5, (100, 1)), columns=['data'])
```

Use the `scipy.stats.normaltest` function:

```
from scipy.stats import normaltest
k2, p = normaltest(df.data)

p
0.796799418250495
```

The function tests the null hypothesis that the data comes from a normal distribution. Higher the value of `p`, higher is the probability that the data is from a normal distribution. Apply a threshold (usually 0.05) above which the null hypothesis cannot be rejected.

Comment: Thanks, that is very useful. The "ladder/gladder" functions run the normaltest automatically itself as well as on a set of possible transformations (log10, sqrt, ...) . I was wondering if there is anything either built in into pandas or anyone knows a package to do so?

Comment: @col.slade Ah, not that I know of. As they say in python, explicit is better than implicit. You'll need to write those transformations yourself but it shouldn't be hard at all, if you use `np.log10`, `np.sqrt`, etc.